# what's the difference between the Altova XMLSpy XSLT transformer and the Saxon XSLT transformer?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there even any difference between the Altova XMLSpy XSLT transformer and the Saxon XSLT transformer?

I mean how do i decide which to use when/if they are identical ?

I am aware that since their implementation is different most probably one would be more "efficient" or "faster"

Btw have anyone given this problem some thoughts before.. and would like to share their findings?

PS: i'm talking about when doing local-development and testing XSLT, how do i decide whether to use Altova / Saxon (i have both i just don't know which to prefer, and whether if i should simply throw a die..)

Comment: I think you'll find that they are the same insofar as they are both reasonably conformant to the W3C specification, and in almost every other respect they are completely different. Try both and see. For example, see what messages you get if you call a user-defined function passing a string instead of an integer, and see which messages you find more helpful. (I'm not asking you to do that because I know the answer, by the way.)

Comment: i think this is a good idea. so basically we would decide which processor we use based on which has better (user-friendly) error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Saxon can be used on any platform where Java runs and additionally on Windows with the Microsoft .NET framework. AltovaXML is a Windows only tool.

As for differences, if you want to embed an XSLT 2.0 processor into your own program then Saxon offers a rich API whilst the API AltovaXML offers is limited to transforming input in the form of a string or a file to output in the form of a string or a file.

A major shortcoming of AltovaXML in my view is its white space treatment, see the section "Whitespace in XML document" in http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?x20_generalinformation.htm.

AltovaXML (the community edition) is the only XSLT 2.0 processor available for "free" that offers schema-aware transformation, so depending on your needs this can be a big plus for AltovaXML.

Note that there are also other XSLT 2.0 processors by now, on the .NET platform you have the choice between the .NET version of Saxon and XQSharp, which is a pure .NET implementation of XQuery and XSLT and certainly integrates better with existing Microsoft XML APIs than Saxon does.

IBM has an XSLT 2.0 processor for its WebSphere pack and Intel has an XSLT 2.0 processor for its SOAP server (not sure whether that is still in beta or a released product).

Comment: does the .NET version of Saxon and XQSharp works for "offline" development? (without even starting the localhost i.e.)

Comment: You can certainly write .NET command line or .NET Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation applications that employ XSLT 2.0 with Saxon .NET or XQSharp. "starting localhost" sounds like ASP.NET, writing ASP.NET application requires a local web server in any case, whether that application uses XSLT or not. But Visual Studio for development comes with its own server that can host ASP.NET applications while developing.